# Floating action button (Fab) like a grid ( horizontal and vertical )

Tags: android, floating-action-button

I search a floating action button and I want the possibility to add button horizontaly for each vertical button like this :

[image]

How can I do this ?

Comment: Show us the code that you tried...

Comment: I would like to know if a library already exist for doing this

Comment: If you search for material floating action button there will be at least two github libraries to create the button. You will however need to create the grid yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

[Boom Menu](https://github.com/Nightonke/BoomMenu)

or modify it for your purposes